# Correct way to stream a `request` request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailgun

I am trying to create a ReadableStream object from a `request`, which eventually I want to pass it into the attachment variable for [mailgun-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js)'s data object:

```
var fileStream = null;
request(String(url)).pipe(fileStream);

msg.attachment = new mailgun.Attachment({
    data: fileStream,
    filename: 'my_custom_name.png',
    knownLength: fileStat.size,
    contentType: 'image/png'});
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but worth giving a try:

```
var stream = new require('stream').PassThrough();

request(String(url)).pipe(stream);

msg.attachment = new mailgun.Attachment({
  data        : stream,
  filename    : 'my_custom_name.png',
  knownLength : fileStat.size,
  contentType : 'image/png'
});
```

`request()` doesn't seem to inherit from `Stream`, so directly passing it as `data` property won't work. Instead, a [`PassThrough`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream is created, which inherits from both `Readable` and `Writable`.

The `Readable` part will be used by the Mailgun class, and the `Writable` part will get the HTTP response data piped into it.

Comment: It's been a while since I finished this, but I think I did something similar to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late, but hopefully still helpful. Just submitted a pull request to have this functionality:

```
var request = require('request');
var file = request("https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");

var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'serobnic@mail.ru',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!',
  attachment: file
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

If it doesn't get merged, you can see it here:
https://github.com/antoniosou/mailgun-js

Comment: Great, thanks! Hopefully, it's been accepted.